# Creating operator with arguments above and below

Tags: math-operators, subscripts

I am working with creating an operator which has too look like this:

[image: Example of the desired symbols]

I wanna make clear that I need to change the arguments many times in my document because I am showing relation properties between the operation. The ideal scenary is that it would work as the $\sum$ operator from LaTeX.

Since I need arguments both above and below, I tried to create an operator in latex by using the following function:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\OperOmega}{\Omega}
```

I worked pretty well until now... However, I am having the following issues. I hope someone can help...

1. The place where I created the operator has an error, asking to put the operator into math mode. However, when I do so, I got a complete destruction of my document.
2. I need to put the symbol < in one of the operations, but I got an error in the compiler. It says I am missing the item.
3. I need to put an $\star$ in one of the subindex and it appers to still have problems.
4. I would like that everything shows strictly above and below if possible. Is it possible without including the `\displaystyle` command?

Here's a minimal code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\OperOmega}{\Omega}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[label =  $\star$]
         \item $\displaystyle\OperOmega_{<}^{\lambda}[P(x)]$ es BLA.
         \item $\displaystyle\OperOmega_{\star}^{\lambda}[P(x)]$ es BLA.
         \item $\displaystyle\OperOmega_{\leq}^{\lambda_{1}}[P(x)]$ es BLA.
    \end{enumerate}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you replace `standalone` to `article`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it.

Once you can overlook the kind and number of variations in writing you can generalize these into one or more macros using `\newcommand`. Mine are just an example from your posted code:

- IF the argument is always P(x), then it should be absorbed too, i.e. no longer be a variable passed
- you can't number macros like `\OS1{}{}`, `\OS2{}{}`, that's why I used some other approach

Benefits:

- your text becomes more legible
- change in one place only to get it right everywhere (hopefully ;-)

```
%\documentclass{standalone} % see clara https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/710046/creating-operator-with-arguments-above-and-below#comment1766031_710046
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% ~~~ shortcuts ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\DeclareMathOperator*{\OperOmega}{\Omega}
\newcommand\OS[2]{$\displaystyle\OperOmega_{#1}^{\lambda}[#2]$}% OperatorSymbol
\newcommand\OSS[2]{$\displaystyle\OperOmega_{#1}^{\lambda_{1}}[#2]$}% OperatorSymbol

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[label =  $\star$]
         \item $\displaystyle\OperOmega_{<}^{\lambda}[P(x)]$ es BLA.
         \item $\displaystyle\OperOmega_{\star}^{\lambda}[P(x)]$ es BLA.
         \item $\displaystyle\OperOmega_{\leq}^{\lambda_{1}}[P(x)]$ es BLA.
    \end{enumerate}

\hrule
    \begin{enumerate}[label =  $\star$]
         \item \OS{<}{P(x)} es BLA.
         \item \OS{\star}{P(x)} es BLA.
         \item \OSS{\leq}{P(x)} es BLA.
    \end{enumerate}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: result]